# Windows10 installation wants drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on an old machine; it is a MSI 945GM2 motherboard with a P4 3.0GHz, 2GB of RAM.

I boot the PC with a DVD disk and after several seconds it ask me for drivers .. but which driver(s)?

I downloaded a driver for the 82801 controller chip, but Windows Installer says it is not able to install it.

I'm looking for drivers for the DVD drive (LG GSA-4167B) and the HD (WD1600JS-00MHB0) but I'm not able to find them.

But why is it looking for these drivers while it is yet able to use that devices (I'm able to browse them..)?

Comment: The Windows installation environment is NOT asking for drives for an optical disk drive, which of course is the exact reason, it's able to use them.  Worth pointing out that your Pentium 4, does not even meet the processor requirements, to even run Windows 10.  The drivers it's looking for are likely the chipset drivers. As I said your processor does not even support the required x86 instructions that Windows 10 requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has turned off the servers for XP updates for the general public; only large corporations or governments can buy the Microsoft service plans required to access them.  That's why you can't update XP.

The motherboard manufacturer, MSI, [does not support anything newer than Windows 7 64-bit](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/945GM2FR_FI_F) on that machine, and [Windows 7 is about to meet the same fate as XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057281/windows-7-support-will-end-on-january-14-2020).

The drivers built in to Windows 10 can sorta-kinda make some things work, and you won't need a special driver for the HDD since Windows 10 knows how to make SATA III work, but as per Microsoft [it will not accept your P4 CPU](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements).

Has the user considered [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) or [LXLE](http://www.lxle.net/)?

Comment: Ok, I can also accept a Win7 installation but it says that it is not possible to update the current XP. Maybe I can clean all the disk but I need to backup all the files. I agree about Linux but the PC is not mine (I own a Debian pc :))

Comment: "That it is not possible to update the current XP." - What?  Can you please in specific detail, by editing your question, explain what you mean by this statement?

Comment: I run the setup within the XP environment, as stated by the setup if run it at the boot. After a couple of steps it shows me a message that tells that the SO upgrade (with the substitution of the files - no wipe out) are not possible and reports a Microsoft page that should me explain how to do it anyway. That page is currently not referred to Win7 but Win10 and I'm not able to find the instruction. Leaving the Win10 idea, I think I will explore the Win7 upgrade, maybe wiping out the disk (after a complete backup..)

Comment: Windows 7 is about to be End of Life, unsupported. Not a good idea. At some time the owner will have to accept the fact that, in the Microsoft environment, the hardware has been obsoleted. A light Linux distro will give it a few years more.

Comment: Ok I solved with Win7 and some backupped files. The problem with Linux distro is that they do not completely support iTunes ...

Comment: Well, neither does Apple, any more: https://www.cnn.com/2019/06/03/tech/itunes-apple-wwdc/index.html Exporting the customer's music library is highly recommended, but that is another issue, but https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-export-itunes-songs-as-mp3-files and https://www.lifewire.com/convert-itunes-songs-to-mp3-2000442 will offer help.